# Getting Invalid character error in angularjs and response value is undefined

Tags: angularjs, json, struts2

I am using angularjs with Struts2.
I am able to send the request from angularjs to the Struts2 action class and get the json object there and set the json in response object in action but while retrieving the json in angularjs getting invalid character error in browser console and in debugging getting undefined for response object. Below is the code for the same:-

```
angularModule.controller('ResultDatabaseCtrl',function($scope,$http){
                        $http.get('/url/test').then(function(response)
                        {
                            $scope.data=response;
                        })
});
```

And in the Struts2 action I am writing the below code:

```
    public String Test() throws ServletException {

        response.setContentType("text/json");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");

        try {
            aggOutput = Delegator.getInstance().processRequest(aggInput);
            response.getWriter().write((String) aggOutput.getValueObject());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Here in the `aggOutput.getValueObject` is having the JSON code in the format below:

```
{ identifier: "id",items: [ { id:"1", name:"ABC", Age:12 },
{  id:"1", name:"PQR", Age:2 }]}
```

While retrieving the data in angularjs from controller getting response is undefined while debugging in browser and in console getting the below error:-

```
SyntaxError: Invalid character

at uc (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:15:466)

at $b (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:82:358)

   at Anonymous function (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:83:272)
  at n (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:7:331)
```

Comment: A response is something returned by Struts2. Without knowing how Struts2 can return data with the response you can't get any object in angular.

Comment: This is NOT a valid json string. See - http://www.json.org/.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the help..Its the JSON format that was causing the issue and also in the data double quotes were there. After correcting that the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the response `Content-Type` to `application/json` from `text/json`.

Comment: Tried that too in action but that also did not worked.

Comment: Could you post the error while using angular.js rather than the minified version?

Answer (score 0):

And also,

```
angularModule.controller('ResultDatabaseCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http){
  $http.get('/url/test').then(function(response)
  {
    $scope.data=response;
  })
}]);
```

You need the dependencies injecting, but that's probably not what is causing the error per se.

Comment: Can you please give one example it would be very helpful. Exactly which dependencies need to inject.

Comment: They're in the code example I posted. The ['$scope', '$http' bit before your function()

Comment: Thanks.. Tried that but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the error function in your code. This will catch the exact error message in response.

```
angularModule.controller('ResultDatabaseCtrl',function($scope,$http){
   $http.get('/url/test')
   .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.sringify(response));
        function(error) {console.log(JSON.sringify(error));}
   );
});
```